# Empty string not equal to empty string in PHP ternary operator expression

Tags: php, string, ternary-operator, is-empty

Could someone explain me the following?

```
$a="";

$a="" ? "" : "muh";

echo $a; 
// returns muh
```

Comment: Blank string evaluates to false.

Comment: Ok, that's the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks you are trying to use [Comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `==`, but instead you are using an [Assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) `=`

Your code is trying to assign `$a` the result of the expression `"" ? "" : "muh"`. An empty string is evaluated as `false` and `$a` is assgined the value of `muh`.

*Let's put some parentheses to make it more obvious:*

```
//$a equals (if empty string then "" else "muh")
$a = ("" ? "" : "muh");

echo $a; // muh


//$a equals (if $a is equal to empty string then "" else muh)
$a = ($a == "" ? "" : "muh"); 

echo $a; //
```